# implement incremental numeric variable in robot keyword

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to create a robot keyword which increments a number everytime it is called, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried several ways of implementing the increments, some just give errors. The ones below go through, but keep the variable at its original value.

```
*** Variables ***
${counter}=  ${1}

*** Keywords ***
my keyword
    ${counter}=  set variable  ${counter+1}
    ${counter}=  evaluate  ${counter} + 1
```

I expect that the variable increses by 1 every time I run my keyword, but it keeps its original value of 1. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
*** Variables ***
${counter}=     ${1}

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    My Keyword
    Log To Console    In test: ${counter}
    My Keyword

*** Keywords ***
my keyword
    ${counter}=  set variable  ${counter+1}
    ${counter}=  evaluate  ${counter} + 1
    Log To Console    In keyword: ${counter}
```

Prints:

```
In keyword: 3
In test: 1
In keyword: 3
```

If you use `Set Test Variable` in `my keyword`, it updates the variable in bigger scope (test scope, not keyword scope).

```
my keyword
    ${counter}=  set variable  ${counter+1}
    ${counter}=  evaluate  ${counter} + 1
    Log To Console    In keyword: ${counter}
    Set Test Variable    ${counter}
```

Now this prints:

```
In keyword: 3
In test: 3
In keyword: 5
```